# The word for a portion of an asset

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes a noun refers to a type of objects, for example, "a virus" always refer to a type of virus, not a unit of a virus. It's difficult to refer to a single unit of a virus. I've heard people saying "a virus particle".

I'm working with digital assets. It seems in finance, "asset" always refers to a type, like "virus". People say: "you need multiple assets to diversify your investments". In another example, "an asset of mine is property", which might be a house, two or many houses.

"asset" as a word does not always refer to a type. In intelligence, "an asset" is an actual piece (or person), like "we have an asset in the Middle East".

What would be the word of choice for a single portion of a digital asset? What if I am to refer to a piece of music, a single crypto kitten, not a type of them? I'm thinking of "asset-piece" or "token", where "token" suffer from the same problem (typically it refers to a type).

Comment: But, in the way you've described, an asset *is* of a type—and, like viruses, can be countable. *I've been infected with two viruses* has the same functionality as *I have have (own) two assets*. Also, viruses can be measured (*it's a weak virus*, *it's a strong virus*) and assets can be measured (*I have $30,000 in assets.*) So, I really don't see what difference you are seeing between the two—or what you mean by *a single piece of a digital asset*.

Comment: Please edit this so it doesn't make people think ***"piece of ass"*** et cetera.

Comment: I'd maybe argue that *asset class* refers to a type, while *asset* actually is singular.  ie "My assets include property." and "Property is one of my asset classes."   Anyways.

Answer (score 1):

How about an **instance**, or an **entity**?

> An instance of a digital asset.
>
> A digital entity (e.g. a file).

Answer (score 0):

The word virion is used quite frequently (though usually in formal contexts) in biology to refer to a single viral particle.

Interesting question, though it seems context specific, e.g. file, dataset, data structure, could all work. There are almost unlimited types of "assets" that can be digitally encoded.